# SML - operator and operand disagree

Tags: sml

I have this simple function:

```
val CLC_seq=
       fn (n) =>
       (Cons (n, find_CLC_seq(COL_seq(n))))
```

When:

```
find_CLC_sqe is : int seq -> int;
COL_seq is: fn: int -> int seq;
```

The complier wrote:

```
Error: operator and operand don't agree
operator domain: int * (Unit -> int seq)
operand: int * int
in expression: 
 (Cons (n, find_CLC_seq(COL_seq(n))))
```

What is the reason? How can I solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not clear what you're trying to do exactly, but the compiler is right to pick you up on it. `find_CLC_seq` returns an `int`, which means your `Cons` is trying to cons an `int` onto an `int`. That makes no sense, because cons is for adding an element to the front of a list (your `Cons` function is expecting to put an `int` on the front of a lazy sequence, a `(Unit -> int seq)`).

I don't know what CLC and COL are, but it looks like either:

Your definition of `CLC_seq` is wrong, because if `find_CLC_seq` is really meant to return an `int`, it doesn't make sense to be using it that way;

OR your definition of `find_CLC_seq` is wrong, and its return type should be `int seq` or a lazy sequence, as the name implies. In that case, the error is in a bit of code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but I still don't get what is the problem. find_CLC_seq returns an int (as I wrote:find_CLC_sqe is : int seq -> int;) . so It will do Cons (int, int). Why the complier see it as Unit -> int seq?

Comment: Yes, your code is trying to cons an int to an int (that's what it means when it says 'operand: int * int'). The Cons constructor doesn't want those arguments; it's meant to be used to cons an int to a sequence. The type of Cons will be `int * (Unit -> int seq) -> (Unit -> int seq)`, which is what it means when it says that input for 'operator domain'. The 'operand' is what you tried to pass it, the 'operator domain' is what you should be passing.

Comment: Did you write find_CLC_seq yourself? If so, did you intend it to return an int? I can see that it does, but is that what you want? From the name of the function, it sounds like it should be returning a sequence, in which case the mistake might be there.

Comment: find_CLC_seq return an int! the compiler wrote me that "find_CLC_sqe is : int seq -> int;". find_CLC_sqe is returing the location of the first number 5 that appear in the sequence.

Comment: Before it, I defined: datatype 'a seq = Nil | Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a seq);.
Maybe this is the problem? Why the complier can't do cons of int*int?

Comment: It can't do cons of int*int because that makes no sense. Your datatype looks fine, wherever you got that from. You're going to have to explain the CLC_seq function is meant to be doing then. Could you post your complete code and the question you are trying to solve so we can see what the code is trying to solve?

Comment: last question, I promise: Why I can't do cons (int*int)? If I want pair of int*int, How I do that?

Comment: Cons adds an element to the head of a list, which might go on for a while. A pair of elements (a 'tuple') by definition has a fixed length, so you can't use Cons to make them. A pair of ints, an `int*int`, is simply made using `(..,..)`. If you want CLC_seq to return a pair of ints, just get rid of the word 'Cons' from the code in your question.